# Periodically restart node express server

Tags: node.js, express, pm2, forever

I have an express application that predictably spikes CPU after running for a while under load.  I'd like to proactively restart it every N minutes in order to avoid the spikes.  It's currently running under `forever`, but I could use `pm2` or some other process manager.  Is there any process manager that can do periodic restarts?  How can I go about accomplishing this with the minimum of added structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it  programmatically with PM2 with the following code.

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');

pm2.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  setTimeout(function worker() {
    console.log("Restarting app...");
    pm2.restart('app', function() {});
    setTimeout(worker, NUM_MILLI_SECONDS);
  }, NUM_MILLI_SECONDS);
});
```

This will restart it every number of given milliseconds. There is also a CRON library you can use.